# Does certificate-based Hyper-V replication work when the CA is offline?

Tags: hyper-v, certificate-authority, hyper-v-server-2012

We are using Hyper-V replication on Windows Server 2012+ outside Active Directory, so we are using SSL certificates issued by our
own internal CA.

When setting up replication, I made sure that both the source host and the replica server had access to the CA server.

However in normal operation due to our network topology, the Hyper-V hosts have no access to the CA server.

This seems to work fine, but I'm wondering whether the Hyper-V hosts will ever need to access the CA server again to check for revoked certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they do - but failure to access the CA will just mean no updated revocation list. I.e. certificates will still be accepted.

Still, obvsiously have a not really good (as in: total crap) network achitecture and the hyper-v hosts should be able to access the ca.